# React input can't type anything

Tags: reactjs

I have an input text and I can't write in it !

I tried to control it like that :

```
handleUserInput(e){
   console.log('ok')
   this.setState({
      newPlayer: e.target.value
   })
}

<input type="text" className="inputTexte" placeholder="Username" value={this.state.newPlayer} onChange={e => this.handleUserInput(e.target.value)} />
```

But even if I just put an input like that :

```
<input type="text" />
```

I can't write in it.

It's drive me crazy...

Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Convert it to arrow `handleUserInput = (e) => { ... }` or bind it in constructor

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
handleUserInput(e){
   console.log('ok')
   this.setState({
      newPlayer: e.target.value
   })
}
```

Most probably you have to bind this value to handler function, inside your constructor,

```
this.handleUserInput= this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
```

Or Change the handler function to fat arrow function like below

```
const handleUserInput = (e)=>{//write your code inside}
```

But before this please the check the developer console and update the error here

Comment: There's no error.

And if I just put a <input type="text" /> I Can't write. So there's a problem

Answer (score -1):

You are setting state the state wrong, you are passing `e.target.value` to `handleChange` function and again using `event.target.value` while setting state

change your input as follows and try

```
<input type="text" className="inputTexte" placeholder="Username" value={this.state.newPlayer} onChange={e => this.handleUserInput(e)} />
```

or change handleUserInput as follows

```
handleUserInput(value){
  console.log('ok')
  this.setState({
    newPlayer: value
   })
}
```

Comment: I tried but nothings change.

I think there's a problem because I can't type even I just do this :
```
<input type="text" />  
```

Comment: can you create a sandbox of your issue and share it

Comment: How can I do that ? this is integrated in a big project

Comment: can you atleast share the whole component code, and once try restarting the server

Answer (score -1):

Define like this

```
handleUserInput(value){
   console.log('ok')
   this.setState({
      newPlayer: value
   })
}
```

because you already passed input value `e.target.value`

```
onChange={e => this.handleUserInput(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: I tried but nothings change. I think there's a problem because I can't type even I just do this : ``` <input type="text" /> ```

Answer (score -1):

State does update synchronously. This means that when React actually performs the update, it is at a later time and the value of the event is lost. This is because React uses a synthetic event wrapper to wrap all DOM events to ensure compatibility across all browsers and this wrapper is emptied after a while to be reused. My proposal is to simply store the event value at a variable, which will ensure it retains its value when the state update does happen.

```
handleUserInput(e){
  console.log('ok')
  const eventValue = e.target.value;
  this.setState({
  newPlayer: eventValue
})
}
```

Also, you call the function with event.target.value as parameter, and then you access the .target.value again, so it does not work.

```
onChange={e => this.handleUserInput(e)}
```

And as described above, inside `handleUserInput` access it via `e.target.value`, the way you had it previous implied that inside the function you were trying to access `e.target.value.target.value`.

Comment: I tried but nothings change. I think there's a problem because I can't type even I just do this : ``` <input type="text" /> ```

Answer (score -1):

It have a code erro, you are pass the event target value in the function but is expected the event only

try:

```
handleUserInput(e){
   console.log('ok')
   this.setState({
      newPlayer: e.target.value
   })
}

<input type="text" className="inputTexte" placeholder="Username" value={this.state.newPlayer} onChange={this.handleUserInput} />
```